# How do add_rowns() mean() with group(), mean(), paste0() using dyply?

Tags: r

I have this (dataframe) and Expected return (output dataframe).
[image]

I thought of doing like this:

```
mydata %>% 
+   filter(Q3=="Var1") %>% 
+   group_by(Q1,year) %>%
+   add_row(Q1= paste0(c(Q1),"median"), Country  = paste0("[",c(Q2),"]"),Q3=Q3, value = mean(.,value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But I can't solve it, any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this problem by separating it into logical blocs and combine (union) them like this ... I wont type out everyline as I got diferent values than you but they are the median indeed as we will see. Also with this in hands and understanding what is going on you can solve the rest:

```
# set up your dummy data
df <- data.frame(Q2 = c    ("A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2","B3","B4","C1","C2","C3","C4","A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2","B3","B4","C1","C2","C3","C4"),
                 Q3 = c(rep("V1", 12), rep("V2",12)),
                 year = rep(seq(2013, 2016, 1),6),
                 value = c(NA, 199, 198, 172, 378, 374, 360,366,10,25,15,22,285,257,253,265,653,645,668,634,129,183,126,138)) %>%
           # generate Q1 as i am to lazy to type that also
           dplyr::mutate(Q1 = stringr::str_sub(Q2, 1,1),
                         # generate a helping column
                         help = ifelse(year %in% c(2013, 2014), TRUE, FALSE))


df1 <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(help == FALSE & Q3 == "V1") %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Q1) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Q1 = paste(Q1, "median"),
                     Q2 = paste0(unique(Q2), collapse = ";"),
                     Q3 = unique(Q3), 
                     year = paste0(min(year), ":", max(year)),
                     value = median(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()

df2 <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(Q3 == "V2") %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Q1) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Q1 = paste(Q1, "median"),
                     Q2 = paste0(unique(Q2), collapse = ";"),
                     Q3 = unique(Q3), 
                     year = paste0(min(year), ":", max(year)),
                     value = median(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()

df3 <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(Q1 %in% c("A", "B") & Q3 == "V1" & help == FALSE) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Q1 = paste(paste0(unique(Q1), collapse = ""), "median"),
                     Q2 = paste0(Q2, collapse = ";"),
                     Q3 = unique(Q3), 
                     year = paste0(min(year), ":", max(year)),
                     value = median(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()

res <- df %>%
    dplyr::select(Q1, Q2, Q3, year, value) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(year = as.character(year)) %>%
    dplyr::union(df1) %>%
    dplyr::union(df2) %>%
    dplyr::union(df3) 

# just to pretty print in the console
as.data.frame(res)

          Q1          Q2 Q3      year value
1          A          A1 V1      2013    NA
2          A          A2 V1      2014 199.0
3          A          A3 V1      2015 198.0
4          A          A4 V1      2016 172.0
5          B          B1 V1      2013 378.0
6          B          B2 V1      2014 374.0
7          B          B3 V1      2015 360.0
8          B          B4 V1      2016 366.0
9          C          C1 V1      2013  10.0
10         C          C2 V1      2014  25.0
11         C          C3 V1      2015  15.0
12         C          C4 V1      2016  22.0
13         A          A1 V2      2013 285.0
14         A          A2 V2      2014 257.0
15         A          A3 V2      2015 253.0
16         A          A4 V2      2016 265.0
17         B          B1 V2      2013 653.0
18         B          B2 V2      2014 645.0
19         B          B3 V2      2015 668.0
20         B          B4 V2      2016 634.0
21         C          C1 V2      2013 129.0
22         C          C2 V2      2014 183.0
23         C          C3 V2      2015 126.0
24         C          C4 V2      2016 138.0
25  A median       A3;A4 V1 2015:2016 185.0
26  B median       B3;B4 V1 2015:2016 363.0
27  C median       C3;C4 V1 2015:2016  18.5
28  A median A1;A2;A3;A4 V2 2013:2016 261.0
29  B median B1;B2;B3;B4 V2 2013:2016 649.0
30  C median C1;C2;C3;C4 V2 2013:2016 133.5
31 AB median A3;A4;B3;B4 V1 2015:2016 279.0
```

This is pretty much what you are looking for and what can be logically done with the data BUT inspecting closely the last two rows I noticed, that the median I calculated has diferent values than you supplied. Therefore I made the manual check:

```
# result line 30 should be calculated from these values:
median(c(129,183,126,138))
[1] 133.5
median(c(198,172,360,366))
[1] 279
```

maybe I understood something wrong - in that case please correct me. If not you can use my code to create the missing lines. Also it is possible to re-write the code as a function which might me recomendable.

Comment: @Cuba, Sorry, I forgot to make the dataframe available.
I understood the solution, I was trying to do everything in one set of code. thank you very much for your availability.